# Refreshing Cache after every service call in spring

Tags: java, spring, caching

I have a implementation in DAO layer like :

```
@Cacheable(value = "features", cacheManager = "springCacheManager")
public List<Feature> getFeaturesFromProjectByRelease(UserDto userDto, int projectId, int releaseId, List<Integer> releasesList) {
   //lets return a valid list with some random data, for simplicity I have returned a blank one here
   return new ArrayList<Feature>();
}
```

I have a service like this:

```
//Get all the features for projects and release
List<Feature> featureList = featureDao.getFeaturesFromProjectByRelease(userDto, projectId, releaseId, releasesList);
try {
      this.refreshFeatureListCache(userDto, projectId, releaseId, releasesList);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      logger.error("Cannot refresh 'features' cache");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

@Async("asyncExecutor")
public CompletableFuture<List<Feature>> refreshFeatureListCache(UserDto userDto, int projectId, int releaseId, List<Integer> releasesList) throws InterruptedException {
    return this.updateFeatureListInCache(userDto, projectId, releaseId, releasesList);
}

@CachePut(value = "features", cacheManager = "springCacheManager")
private CompletableFuture<List<Feature>> updateFeatureListInCache(UserDto userDto, int projectId, int releaseId, List<Integer> releasesList) {
    List<Feature> featureList = featureDao.getFeaturesFromProjectByRelease(userDto, projectId, releaseId, releasesList);
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(featureList);
}
```

I have an executor service 'asyncExecutor' running as well.

I am not so sure if the above will work.

I am looking for an alternative solution if this won't work where I will read the 'featureList' from cache if available and then immediately call another ASYNCHRONOUSLY service that will update/refresh the cache by actually hitting the database. 
Any suggestions on this will be helpful!

**EDIT:**
Adding problem statement to better clarify the challenge:

1. Get the data from database. If the request is made for the first time then call the actual service and cache the data.
2. If the request is made for the 2nd time onward, retrieve the data from cache to avoid long waiting time for the front end user. Once the request is serve from cache, immediately call the service again and update/refresh the cache data by actually calling the time taking service method ASYNCHRONOUSLY, so that the user doesn't have to wait with frozen/loading state UI.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that will work, but if it doesn't you could clear the cache manually and then call the cached method again, like:

```java
    public class ExampleService {

        private final CacheManager cacheManager;

        private final FeatureDAO featureDao;

        public ExampleService(CacheManager cacheManager, FeatureDAO featureDao) {
            this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
            this.featureDao = featureDao;
        }

        @Cacheable(value = "features", cacheManager = "springCacheManager")
        public List<Feature> getFeaturesFromProjectByRelease(UserDto userDto, int projectId, int releaseId, List<Integer> releasesList) {
            //lets return a valid list with some random data, for simplicity I have returned a blank one here
            return new ArrayList<Feature>();
        }

        @Async("asyncExecutor")
        public CompletableFuture<List<Feature>> refreshFeatureListCache(UserDto userDto, int projectId, int releaseId, List<Integer> releasesList) throws InterruptedException {
            return this.updateFeatureListInCache(userDto, projectId, releaseId, releasesList);
        }

        private CompletableFuture<List<Feature>> updateFeatureListInCache(UserDto userDto, int projectId, int releaseId, List<Integer> releasesList) {
            Cache featuresCache = cacheManager.getCache("features");
            featuresCache.clear();
            List<Feature> featureList = featureDao.getFeaturesFromProjectByRelease(userDto, projectId, releaseId, releasesList);
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(featureList);
        }
}
```

Comment: I am looking here for an in-built provision of spring here that could solve the problem statement. I am also open to any external framework as well if that solves the problem.